# show Image from datatable in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I have bind data on on-load () function of my asp page and I can retrieve all data, but unfortunately I am unable to see the image. I have attached code, please give me some idea how can I do this? Help me to show image in grid view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">

             <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
             <HeaderStyle BackColor="#C19E45" ForeColor="White" />
             <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#3333CC" ForeColor="Red" />
</asp:GridView>


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = client.viewClients();
    DataTable  newdt = new DataTable();//for filtering data
     newdt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Father/Husband", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Cnic", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Occupation", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Present_Address", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Telephone", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Permanent_address", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Nominee_name", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Nominee_address", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Nominee_cnic", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("nominee_no", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(string));
     newdt.Columns.Add("registeration_no", typeof(string));


    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        DataRow nrow = newdt.NewRow();  //creating newRow
       // byte[] imgarray = (byte[])row["image"];
       // System.Drawing.Image img = client.byteArrayToImage(imgarray);
        nrow["id"]=row["id"];
        nrow["Name"] = row["name"];
        nrow["Father/Husband"] = row["relation_of"];
        nrow["Cnic"] = row["applicant_cnic"];
        nrow["Occupation"] = row["occupation"];
        nrow["Present_Address"] = row["present_address"];
        nrow["Telephone"] = row["telephone"];
        nrow["Phone"] = row["mobile"];
        nrow["Email"] = row["email"];
        nrow["Permanent_address"] = row["permanent_address"];
        nrow["Nominee_name"] = row["nominee_name"];
        nrow["Nominee_address"] = row["nominee_address"];
        nrow["Nominee_cnic"] = row["nominee_cnic"];
        nrow["nominee_no"] = row["nominee_no"];
        nrow["Image"] = row["image"];
        nrow["registeration_no"] = row["registeration_no"];

        newdt.Rows.Add(nrow);

    }
    GridView2.DataSource = newdt;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

This is the output getting from the code
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the image column created as a string, it's not a string.You need to create an image template in your `GridView` control and bind the image inside the template to the binary data of your image:

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
    var table = new DataTable();

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name,Image FROM Colour",connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(table);

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    GridView2.DataSource = table;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>Image</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("Image") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image")) : string.Empty %>' alt="image" height="100" width="200" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Output:**

[image: Showing images in grid view]

Answer (score 0):

the best answer for this is tomake handler 
http://codedisplay.com/display-images-in-gridview-from-sql-server-database-table-using-asp-net-c-vb-net/